# Getting dup key for fields in different table

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoDb and maybe I do not understand how it works.
I created the following tables:

```
User:
=====
email: string;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
password?: string;
role: string;

Role:
=====
title: string;
permissios: string;
```

I created 2 roles: admin and operator without problem.

But having problem to create more than 1 user.

I'm using typegoose, and I'm trying to create new user and getting duplicate key for field role.title which is in role table (but there is no dependency between the tables? role defined as string in user table).

```
"E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.users index: role.title_1 dup key: { : null }"
```

**Example of code creating the user:**

```
const user = new this.userModel({...profile});

    try {
        return await user.save();
    } catch (e) {
```

**the profile is:**
{"email":"dsd.sdsd@gmail.com","password":"123456","firstName":"Israel","lastName":"Lavi","role":"admin","_id":"5b126333e4a2c85c60592e52"}

What is wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Once upon a time you put this field in the current mongoose model and marked it `unique`. Since then you removed that code and changed the documents, but that does not alter the "indexes" already created. You need to drop all existing indexes on the collection and let the mongoose startup recreate the only ones you are actually using.

Comment: @Neil Lunn Thanks for your reply, this solved the problem!